# Comparing two lists and seeing if the first list has matching numbers of the second

Tags: python

Comparing the two using a for loop and if statement it keeps giving me a IndexError: list index out of range.

It should print out the number of the first loop followed by if it is in the second loop at which index

```
for i in firstList:
    if firstList[i] in secondList:
        print(f"{firstList[i]} at index {secondlist.index(firstList[i])}")
    else:
        print(f"{firstList[i]} not found in list")
```

Comment: start your debugging with `for i in firstList: print(i)` and look what it says.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, i cant believe i didnt see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reasoning behind Problem

The problem is that the variable `i` does not take the index, but the element itself at the index.
You have to see if the element is contained in `secondList`, just replace `firstList[i]` with `i`

The code implemented will look something like this:

```
for element in firstList:
    if element in secondList:
        print(f"{firstList[i]} at index {secondlist.index(firstList[i])}")
    else:
        print(f"{firstList[i]} not found in list")
```

#### Advice

Some advice i would give you would be:

1. If you want you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to find an intersection between sets, after the lists are converted to set

for example:

```
>>> firstList = [1,2,3,4]
>>> secondList = [52,4,2]

>>> set.intersection(set(firstList),set(secondList))
{2,4}
```

2. Use print statements and `type` to check if what the code is doing is what is supposed to be doing.

an example would be:

```
for i in firstList:
    print(f"the value of i is {i}")
    print(f"i is a {type(i)}")

    # if firstList[i] in secondList:
    #     print(f"{firstList[i]} at index {secondlist.index(firstList[i])}")
    # else:
    #     print(f"{firstList[i]} not found in list")
```

### Useful external Links

1. [w3school set.intersection() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp)
2. [geeksforgeek set.intersection() method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intersection-function-python/)

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```py
for i in firstList:
```

the variable `i` takes successively the **values** of the **elements** of `firstList`.
This is apparently not what you want because you are using these elements as indexes for the second list.

In your case there is no need to use the indices of the list, you can use the items directly

```py
for element in enumerate(firstList):
    if element in secondList:
        print(f"{element} at index {secondlist.index(element)}")
    else:
        print(f"{element} not found in list")
```

If you want to use the indices anyways you can use

```py
for i in range(len(firstList)):
    ...
```

`len(firstList)` gives you the length of the list and `range` allows `i` to take the values `0` to `len(firstList)-1`, effectively providing you with a way to iterate over the list.